# Jenkins Active Choice Parameter with Multi Select displays comma separated output instead of space separated output

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Jenkins Active Choice Parameter with Multi Select choice type option, displaying comma separated values when trying to print them in console.

Steps i have followed:

1, Active choice parameter with groovy contains `return ["Aaa","Bbb","Ccc","Ddd"]`

2, In pipeline script section added `echo "TEST_VALUE: ${TEST_VALUE}"`

Build with Paarameters looks as shown in the figure, where i select multiple choices.
[image: Build With Parameters]

after running the build, in console it is printing `TEST_VALUE: Bbb,Ccc,Ddd` comma seperated values.

Is it possible to print output with space seperated like `TEST_VALUE: Bbb Ccc Ddd`?

Answer (score 0):

It is **List**. Use "${TEST_VALUE.join(' ')"} for joining list elements